# Distributive function of continous variable

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

I am supposed to find distributive function for:

$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{c-|x-d|}{c^{2}} &  x\in \left [ d-c,d+c \right ] \\ 
0 & else 
\end{matrix}\right.$

,where $c,d\in \mathbb{R}$ and c>0. I do not know how to set boundaries for integral as I have there absolute value.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It's embedded in your definition of $ f(x) $ because $ d-c \leqslant x \leqslant d+c $.

Comment: @WADon but there is absolute value, so it means that integral should be divided in two parts

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the range for $x$ is still the interval $[d-c, d+c]$.  The result you want is then $$F(X) = \int_{d-c}^X \frac{c-|x-d|}{c^2} ~dx . $$  Then obtain two expressions, one when $d-c \leqslant X \leqslant d $ and a second for $ d < X \leqslant d+c $.

Comment: @WADon can you tell me, why is it like this?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you need.  In your density function $f(x)$, for $x \leqslant d$ the absolute value can be dropped, and $$ f(x) = \frac{c-(d-x)}{c^2}.  $$ This can be integrated over any interval $[-d,X]$ for which $X \leqslant d$.  When $X > d$, the modulus changes sign, and in this case you can evaluate, $$F(X) = \int_{d-c}^d \frac{x-(d-x)}{c^2} dx + \int_d^X \frac{x-(x-d)}{c^2} dx. $$ I hope that is clearer.

Comment: @WADon why you have there the second integral from d to X, then why you have in the integral in numerator x instead of c?

Comment: What is the source of your exercise?

Comment: @callculus I do not know, if I understand your question. It is exercise given by teacher

Comment: In answer.  (1). The first $x$ should be $c$.  My error, for which apologies.  (2) The two integrals are necessary when $X > d$.  We have to divide the full range, from $d-c$ to $X$, into the two sub-intervals.  In the first we have $|x-d|=d-x$ And in the second $|x-d|=x-d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to make a case decision due the absolute value term.

$-|x-d|=\begin{cases} -(-x+d), x\leq d \\ -(x-d), x> d  \end{cases}$

All you need to know is how to transform an absolute value function into a piecewise-defined function. Here the pdf can be written as well as

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{c+x-d}{c^2}, d-c<x\leq d \\ \frac{c-x+d}{c^2}, d<x\leq d+c  \\ 0, \textrm{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

Then the cdf is

$$F(x)=\begin{cases} 0, x\leq  d-c\\ \int_{d-c}^{x}\frac{c+t-d}{c^2} \, dt, d-c<x\leq d \\ \int_{d-c}^{d}\frac{c+t-d}{c^2} \, dt+\int_{d}^{x}\ \frac{c-t+d}{c^2} \, dt,  d<x\leq d+c  \\ 1, x>d+c\end{cases}$$

Is it comprehensible? If yes, then you have to calculate the integrals.

Comment: I just have one question, why is there as a boundary x?

Comment: Because the cdf $F(x)$ depends on $x$. What one can do to replace x and dx by t and dt or any other variable, so that the integration variable is different from the upper limit (I have changed it). But at the end it doesn´t matter.